# Получить все ссылки из строки

Tags: php

Есть строка, содержащая, помимо прочего, следующие вхождения:

```
"backgroundImage":"http://[url]"
```

Вместо `url`, соответственно, ссылка на изображение. Как можно было бы получить из строки все эти ссылки?

Comment: Что значит все?

Comment: Что вы подразумеваете под "Получить"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$string = "this is my friend website http://example.com I think it is cool, but this is cooler https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/950006/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8 :)";
$regex = '/\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|$!:,.;]*[A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|$]/i';
preg_match_all($regex, $string, $matches);
$urls = $matches[0];
// go over all links
foreach($urls as $url) 
{
    echo $url.'<br />';
}
```

Comment: @sanmai :))))))